# cgroups between containers

Tags: linux, container, cgroups, kubernetes

I am trying to find out a way to move a process back to the original cgroup after I moved it to a new cgroup under my hierarchy.
The situation is k8s cluster, I have a pod on a node (container) and I run an ephemeral container sharing the same IPC + it is privileged.
I am able to do

```
mkdir /sys/fs/cgroup/newone
echo 1 > /sys/fs/cgroup/newone/cgroup.procs
```

(1 = the pod's process, since we share pid namespace)
but then when I try to do
`echo 1 > /proc/1/root/sys/fs/cgroup/group.procs` I get r/o error, which I assume is because the pod process has the cgroup mounted as ro, so I can't access it.
According to cgroups v2 docs (which is what I'm dealing with):

> The writer must have write access to the "cgroup.procs" file of the common ancestor of the source and destination cgroups.

This means I have to have the ability to move it back, so I'm wondering how I can access it?

Answer (score 0):

I found out that I need to `nsenter` the target cgroup then mount it then it works!